# Bypassing the Google Image Search

Tags: google-image-search

i've been searching for script that can bypass image search in google.

For example...If a image in my site is indexed by google image search then when the google user click on that image a page opens where the image is displayed and my site is shown at the backgrund.

They are many site that can overcome this google indexing and automatically redirect it to the webpage where the image was present.

I'm getting 600 hits a day just by google image results,but i want the users to get images by looking at my site,instead of showing on a popup sort of

Comment: But now iframe killer is not working in google image search !!!

Answer (score 1):

I may be over-simplifying, but isn't it a matter of checking if your site is the "top frame"?

```
if (self.location != top.location){
  top.location = self.location;
}
```

(or some facsimile)

*Unless they're embedding custom content within your site's page, in which case you can probably run a script to check for a "known google DOM element" and, when present, do your own hijacking/redirecting.*

Comment: I believe this works, when I do a search for 'bunny' the first image does exactly what the OP is asking for, and the site contains exactly this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force your website to properly load for visitors that come from Google Images, you just need to employ a [frame-killing script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller) like the one below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (top != self) top.location.replace(location);
</script>
```